# If there is an internal command and an external command (program) of the same name, which one will be executed by default?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

`bash` has an internal command called `kill`, and also in Linux, there is an external command (program) called `kill`.

When I execute `kill` in `bash`, the internal command `kill` is executed.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a setting that I can change to make the external command be
   executed instead of the internal command by default (without specifying the
   full path of the external command of course).
2. Is it a standard behavior for the internal command to be executed
   instead of the external command by default in all (major) shells, or is it just
   a `bash` thing?

Comment: You can try alias kill='/bin/kill'. alias is prior to builtin and external command.

Comment: _Why_ would you want the external command to be the default?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `env` to invoke it.

   ```
   $ env kill
   kill: not enough arguments
   $ kill
   kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
   ```
2. All shells and command processors.

Answer (score 2):

To your first question:
Yes, there is a setting to make the external command be executed instead of the internal command by default.

You can turn builtin off by

```
enable -n COMMAND
```

You can turn builtin on by

```
enable COMMAND
```

or you can change the priority of the command. The priority of bash command is：

- alias, it's highest
- function
- builtin
- external command in $PATH

To your second question:
I think you can always assume internal command is prior to external command. It's not only a bash thing.